# Delete a value of an array if exist on another array

Tags: jquery

I have a set of data on the table. Which are all owners.

```
  <table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="John" onclick="deleteVal('John');" type="button"> Delete </button>
    </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="owner[]" value="John"> John </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="Mike" onclick="deleteVal('Mike');" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Mike"> Mike </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="Sam" onclick="deleteVal('Sam');" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Sam"> Sam </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When the submit button is clicked all owners are stored to this `final_owner` field. This is what i've tried.

```
<button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
FINAL OWNERS: <input type="text" id="final_owner">


 $('#submit').on('click', function() {
      var owner_value = [];
  var del_owners = document.getElementById('deleted_owners').value
      $('input[name="owner[]"]').each(function() {
          owner_value.push($(this).val());
      });
      $("#final_owner").val(owner_value);
});
```

Next is Each time I click **Delete Button** the owners name is stored to the `deleted_owners` input field. Which I already made.

My question is how can I remove from the array of `final_owner` field if the owner is already exist on the `delete_owners` input field.

```
<input type="text" id="deleted_owners">.
```

Comment: [Search for the deleted owner in the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and then [remove the entry from the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: yes I can get the values of `var del_owners = document.getElementById('deleted_owners').value` but if it exist on `delete_owners` field it will not appear on `final_owner`

Comment: check answer now  , when you click delete it fills with deleted owners opposite to final owners  see console  when clicking submit

Answer (score 0):

last line in $('#submit').on('click')... You can try this.

```
    var deleted_owners = $("#deleted_owners").val()
    var current_final_owner = $("#final_owner").val()

    var new_final_owner = current_final_owner.filter(item => !deleted_owners.inculdes(item))

    $("#final_owner").val(new_final_owner )
```

***Edited***

Answer (score -2):

try this  with  add delete buttons

Using Sets 
when clicking on add,delete buttons

get our final_owner array from set

```
  Array.from(deleted_owner);
```

check live example :
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-goldstine-wf01q

Comment: People tend to downvote answers that rely on the reader to go to an external site.

Comment: if the `delete button` is clicked sir the array is stored to the `deleted_owners` field when it exist on the `delete_owners` field after clicking submit it will not appear on it

Comment: at first sir is to insert the `deleted_owners` into the field so it is 2 fields. Next is clicking the submit button. If it exist in `deleted_owners` field it will not appear on `final_owner` source code almost ok